# What are the white brackets around a questions stats

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, design

Today I noticed the question about writing a paper in algebraic geometry [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8769/how-can-i-write-a-paper-in-algebraic-geometry) had something funky with it on the front page. It had big white brackets around its question stats.

What is this?

Comment: @Jeff: This is not "by design"; it is a bug in the site's visual appearance, and can be fixed if you let Jin have a look at it. Please remove the tag. (I know, this comment won't even reach you since you haven't actually commented on the question, and that's "by design" too, *sigh*...)

Comment: @rahul no, comments can target editors of the question as well.

Comment: @Jeff: Oh, all the rumours I had heard indicated otherwise. My apologies. But do you agree that this is issue is not by design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brackets around the stats box are part of the site design. Quoting [Jin's design rationale](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site):

> I wanted to add subtle math related elements to aid the visuals. I was careful to not over- do it incase it made the site look cheesy.
>
> - Stats box[votes, answers, views], I put a very subtle matrix bracket around it. I kept the coloring very faint, so when repeated across multiple rows they won't make the site look boxy.

I assume that you noticed them now because `algebraic-geometry` might be one of your "interesting tags", giving the question a blue background on the front page. That background makes the bracket really stand out awkwardly. I was going to post a bug about this, but I guess you got to it first. You should retag this question with `bug` and `design` so that Jin will see it.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly correct. I will make the suggested edit.